Get Active Directory Local Administrator account name using C#
I was try to get AD LAPS admin Account name using C#. I got MS documents that they mention msLAPS-Password attribute Contains Json of values {"n":"Administrator","t":"654wdf684","p":"eeicheubcweufbvcuiacb#dfv244wefv"}.But,In my domain Controller Computer object had not set for that attribute:

any one can explain how I get local admin name using C#.
Did any one Explain How I get Local Admin Account Name using C#

Edit: Definitely check your permissions on the account you’re running this on. If you don’t have permissions, msLAPS will not return the password. This command was typed on my phone, but don’t just run powershell you copy paste from stack overflow. Check it first. Point being, this should set your account with the permissions to read LAPS.
Set-AdmPwdReadPasswordPermission -OrgUnit "OU=YourComputers,DC=YourDomain,DC=com" -AllowedPrincipals "YourAccountOrGroup"

Obviously, make sure LAPS is set up correctly to begin with.
And then I’d force an update for the password, just in case.
Invoke-AdmPwdResetPassword -ComputerName "ComputerName"

Then, here’s how I might approach tackling it. I don’t know your specific approach you’re taking. But maybe this may help you if the process you’re using is the problem.
try
    {
        using (DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath))
        {
            using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry))
            {
                searcher.Filter = "(objectClass=computer)";
                searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(attributeName);

                SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();

                if (result != null && result.Properties.Contains(attributeName))
                {
                    string adminPassword = result.Properties[attributeName][0].ToString();
                    //If successful, you’ll have the password here in adminPassword. 
                }
                else
                {
                   //If unsuccessful, sorry bud, nice try. Find a way to blame Rust developers somehow. 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       // You done messed up. Think about what you did to get here. 
    }

Wish I had a solution for you. In my experience, LDAPs were really frustrating to work with in C#. We had memory leaks related to the DirectorySearcher, if I remember correctly.

I tried out this But msLAPS-Password attribute still not set. Actual problem is. I need Local admin Name for every computer. There is no  one attribute in computer object for set local admin name. I want to find which attribute is response for store local admin name. and get through C# code. However, Thanks for your information
